# Drag and drop widget code

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have been asked by my boss at work to look into allowing widgets on our home page that can be dragged and dropped and the setup saved for each logged in user (or maybe done by cookies so user doesn't need to be logged in).

Are there any out of the box (preferably free) libraries that can be used? If it requires server side functionality then that's got to be c#/.NET.

I can probably put something together myself but it seemed very much like it is reinventing the wheel. :)

And this is my first question just asking for a recommendation so I'm not sure if this is the right place or if I should put in more details.

An example of the kind of thing I want is http://www.google.com/ig.

And sorry if this isn't a well formed question. I wasn't sure where else or how else to ask it. :)

Comment: depends on how customizable you want it. [jQuery-UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) and cookies or localStorage is probably enough to get what you want

Comment: @zzzzBov: Currently the spec goes as far as "Oooh... I saw this on another site. Can we do this?" so I'm looking at it not needing to be too customisable. One of the things that I want it to do is to snap into columns. Does jQuery-UI do that out of the box or would I need to code it up with draggable widgets with droppable columns to put them in?

Comment: In that case, just use [jQuery-UI's `sortable`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/). It's pretty easy to use for multiple groups of items.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Oh yes. I must admit I skipped over that because I interpreted it as sorted, rather than allowing it to be custom arrangable. That does look like what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery & jQuery-UI will do this out of the box if you use the `sortable` function. [The "portlets" demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#portlets) seems to fit your description. You'll still need to save state manually, but that shouldn't be too difficult with an event listener.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good tutorial of how to build something similar to Google's IG by using ASP.NET AJAX. The source code is a bit outdated, but you can get an idea of what should be done on the client and on the server and re-use the code:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/MakingGoogleIG.aspx

Also take a look here:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/drag_drop.aspx